# How can I add an icon in a label?

Tags: label, anychart

I have 2 questions need your help.

1. I would like to add a button on each plot to be a setting button. I use label with event listener and it works well ( as shown in attached file). However, my client asked me to change from normal text to graphic icon? How should I proceed?
2. As you can see from the attached image, the third plot is macd series. The value rage is from -3e-8 to 3e-8 (by my observation). I manually set the maximum and minimum, and it get incorrect scale as shown.

   - How should I set the maximum and minimum for yScale?
   - I don't know how to get maximum and minimum value from a series. Can you suggest me?

[image: here]

Comment: are you sure if image attached?

Comment: Oh! I just found that I cannot attached the image. So I provide by a link instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1 – Unfortunately, the current version of AnyChart doesn't provide an opportunity to add custom-made buttons inside the chart. But you can use a trick and use stage based layout. It means that the container includes a stage. The stage includes the stock chart all other elements by layers. Using this approach you can place an image (icon) upon the plot and set a listener just as for the 'settings' label.
For details, please, check the sample in the comment below.

A2 - We are planning to fix this behavior in 8.4.2 update (approximately by the end of November 2018).
I will notify you when the fix becomes available.
As a temporary workaround, you can get min /max value from your MACD indicator. For details, please, check the sample in the comment below.
You can apply min/max to the yScale of plot #0 like this:

```
chart.plot(0).yScale().minimum(minValue);
chart.plot(0).yScale().maximum(maxValue);
```

Comment: Here is a sample which describes how to place an image and use it as a button - https://playground.anychart.com/haI76uCt/0

Comment: This one shows how to get min and max value of MACD indicator series - https://playground.anychart.com/5fOLFVFE/0

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to inform you that we have released 8.4.2 update which brings many fixes and improvements. This update also includes a fix on the issue you reported. Now calculation of min/max of Y-scale works properly with small values. Update your binaries to get the fix.